# Generate a url from a dropdown

Tags: json, google-maps

Good morning,

I have the following issue.

I'm trying to setup a distance calculator from google maps.

Google is using its own api under that format:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/output?parameters

The output can be json or xml.

The idea is to use latitude and longitude to code the url:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=25.479838,-80.422374&destinations=25.55727,-80.33372

That's an example of how the api provides the output.

Now, I want to be able to generate the url from a list of latitudes and longitudes I have.

Both fields would be a dropdown with autocomplete (the datalist function seems useful for that)

And once I click on a button like Calculate distance, it will generate the url from the 2 inputs I chose, and run it, In order to provide me the output.

The output would be in json so we should also find a way to have it interpreted in html.

I really would appreciate some help on that.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) endpoint:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/output?parameters
```

doesn't support `JSONP` you might want to utilize [Distance Matrix Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) as part of the Google Maps Javascript API.

**Example**

```js
function calc() {
    var originVals = $('#origins').val();
    var destVals = $('#destinations').val();
    var modeVal = $('#modes').val();
    calculateDistances(originVals, destVals, modeVal,printInfo);
}


function printInfo(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
        console.log('An error occured: ' + status);
        return;
    }

    var output = JSON.stringify(response, null, 2);
    $("#output").text(output);

}


function calculateDistances(originVals, destVals, mode, callback) {

    var origins = [];
    originVals.forEach(function (val) {
        var ll = val.split(',');
        origins.push(new google.maps.LatLng(ll[0], ll[1]));
    });

    var destinations = [];
    destVals.forEach(function (val) {
        var ll = val.split(',');
        destinations.push(new google.maps.LatLng(ll[0], ll[1]));
    });

    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
      {
          origins: origins,
          destinations: destinations,
          travelMode: mode.toUpperCase()
      }, callback);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
<body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <label for="modes">Travel Modes</label>            
                    <select id="modes">
                        <option value="driving">Driving</option>
                        <option value="walking">Walking</option>
                        <option value="bicycling">Bicycling</option>
                        <option value="transit">Transit</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="origins">Origins</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="destinations">Destinations</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select id="origins" multiple="multiple">
                        <option value="49.256149, -123.074132">Vancouver+BC</option>
                        <option value="47.608136, -122.309813">Seattle</option>
                    </select>        
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="destinations" multiple="multiple">
                        <option value="37.749624, -122.442407">San+Francisco</option>
                        <option value="48.430068, -123.365541">Victoria+BC</option>
                    </select>     
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input value="Calculate" type="button" onclick="calc();" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <span>Result:</span>
        <pre style="background-color: #c0c0c0" id="output"></pre>
 </body>
```

Comment: Is there any way to couple that to a jquery autocomplete ? See I have a list of more than 200 addresses, and I'd like to be able to chose 2 of them entering in 2 fields (origin + destination) and then click on the button to have the output.

Comment: See I have 2 pieces of code now:

1) the autocomplete jquery that is working
2) the distance calculating matrix

Separately they work, but, I want to use the jquery autocomplete in  order to input the addresses.

In the distance matrix I have to manually enter the address.